# Is it possible install one instance of Trac for multiple independent projects?

Tags: hosting, trac

I want to set up an SVN/Trac environment for multiple projects, something like the GitHub. It will host multiple projects with multiple developers in each. For simplicity the developers can be independent from other projects. I want to setup this environment for every project automatically, from a registration page.

What would be your recommendation? Particularly is it possible to do with Trac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to host [multiple projects](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects) with Trac, last time I checked there was no automated process for creating new environments. I suspect however it wouldn't be difficult to create front end to the [trac-admin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin) and [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch09s02.html) command line tools with your preferred server side web scripting tool.

Comment: You can pass all the required arguments to trac-admin.   So yes, a simple wrapper will let you create new trac instances from a web page.  Might look at http://www.coderesort.com as well; one of the other Trac devs runs that.

Comment: Do you mean that one project's members would not be able to see other projects?

Comment: Permissions can be configured on a per-project basis, if you use Apache you can authenticate against virtually anything so one login can be given permissions on any project, none at all, and everything in between.